# Why are my tests occasionally passing and occasionally failing? (Jest, Mongoose, MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, jestjs

I have a setup file for my tests that looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.promise = global.Promise;

async function removeAllCollections() {
  const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
  for (const collectionName of collections) {
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName];
    await collection.deleteMany();
  }
}

async function dropAllCollections() {
  const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
  for (const collectionName of collections) {
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collections[collectionName];
    try {
      await collection.drop();
    } catch (error) {
      // Sometimes this error happens, but you can safely ignore it
      if (error.message === 'ns not found') return;
      // This error occurs when you use it.todo. You can
      // safely ignore this error too
      if (error.message.includes('a background operation is currently running'))
        return;
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
}

export default function setupDB(databaseName) {
  // Connect to Mongoose
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const url = `mongodb://127.0.0.1/${databaseName}`;
    await mongoose.connect(
      url,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      },
      err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          process.exit(1);
        }
      }
    );
  });

  // Cleans up database between each test
  afterEach(async () => {
    await removeAllCollections();
  });

  // Disconnect Mongoose
  afterAll(async () => {
    await dropAllCollections();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });
}
```

I am then writing tests like this:

```
import User from 'db/models/User';
import setupDB from 'utils/setupDbForTesting';

setupDB('mongoose_bcrypt_test');
it('correctly hashes and salts passwords', async done => {
  // create a user a new user
  const newUser = new User({
    username: 'jmar777',
    password: 'Password123'
  });

  await newUser.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  const user = await User.findOne({ username: 'jmar777' });
  user.comparePassword('Password123', function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    expect(isMatch).toBeTruthy();
  });

  user.comparePassword('123Password', function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) throw err;
    expect(isMatch).toBeFalsy();
  });
  done();
});
```

However, every other time I run these tests, they pass (or fail) so for every time T that the tests pass, T + 1 they will fail. My question is - why?

The tests fail because user (in the callback for User.findOne) returns null, even though the user has been saved.

I think the issue lies in the tearing down of the database, but I really can't see any problems. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If u have any new insights about this, pls share. I am experiencing the exact same, with additional weird errors that sometimes happen and sometimes not, Even though I do delete all the data after each test.